# Are AWS IAM role trust relationships comparable to resource based policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-iam

tl;dr at the bottom if you're familiar with the behavior if IAM roles when it comes to trust relationships.

**Setup I created to describe my question:**

The four roles

```
arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/A
arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/B
arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/X
arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/Y
```

and a user `arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:user/Test` who is able to assume the roles `A` and `B` directly via trust relationship:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:user/Test"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

The user `Test` is just for me to switch into role `A` and `B` easily. In the following I use "having assumed role `A` or `B`" as a starting point which is easy to do via `aws sts assume-role` on your CLI.

**role A configuration**

inline policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/X",
                "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/Y"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The trust relationship is like mentioned above and shouldn't be relevant.

**role B configuration**

It doesn't have any additional config except the irrelevant trust relationship above.

**role X configuration**

trust relationship:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

**role Y configuration**

trust relationship:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/B"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

To sum up the differences: `A` has access granted to `X` and `Y` as inline policy. `B` has nothing like that but `B` is explicitly granted in the trust relationship of `Y`. `X` only allows acces for the account, not a specific user.

**The test with A**

If you assume `A` calling `aws sts get-caller-identity` should return something like

```
{
    "UserId": "<role-id>:test-session-A",
    "Account": "<account-id>",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::<account-id>:assumed-role/A/test-session-A"
}
```

If you now do `aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/X --role-session-name a-assume-x` you do get a valid response with credentials. If you do the same for `Y` you get `AccessDenied [...] User [...] is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole [...]`.

That does make sense because `Y` has no trust relationship with `A`.

**The test with B**

If you assume `B` calling `aws sts get-caller-identity` should return something like

```
{
    "UserId": "<role-id>:test-session-B",
    "Account": "<account-id>",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::<account-id>:assumed-role/B/test-session-B"
}
```

Now it's the other way round. If you try to assume `X`, you get `Access Denied` and assuming `Y` works.

Assuming `Y` works because of the explicit grant of role `B`. We also use that when we assume `A` or `B` with the user `Test` in the first place. What is confusing to me is that assuming `X` doesn't work. The behavior itself makes sense. You allow anything in the account to assume `X` but you need a policy to grant access to a specific user.

**tl;dr - my question**

If you explicitly grant one specific principal access to a role, the principle gets direct access - no additional policy needed. This behaves like resource-based policies.

However, if you add a whole account as trust relationship, this behaves like a permission boundary. You can get access, but you have to create a policy for a principal inside the boundary to actually be able to assume.

This confuses me. What are trust relationships? What is the rule behind that behavior?

Bonus question: Does this also apply to other Services which can be in trust relationship like Lambda or RDS?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with that bonus question. Are you asking whether the policies for other services behave the same way?

Comment: If you have someting like "Service": "rds.amazonaws.com" as a principal you also have to attach the role to a rds instance before it can actually do what the role contains as permissions. Makes sense as well. What would be interesting if there are cases the other way round as well. Like you specify a specific function without adding the role or the right to assume the role on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure how to answer this since you basically already know what trust relationships are.
They specify how can assume a role, specifically they can

- grants access to a specific entity: role, user, idp, ... and / or
- grants access to a specific account to delegate access

In the first case that is all you need.

In the second case you additionally need an attached policy that allows you an `assumeRole` operation. That account-granting includes your own account. A role without a trust relationship would not be assumable by anyone, not in the same account and not cross-account. Not sure why it way decided to be that way I could imagine that the reason was basically *"just because the role is inside your account not everybody in that account should be able to assume it"*.

This is identical to how e.g. KMS key policies work.

---

They do not fully match how resource-based policies work according to [the policy evaluation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html) but mostly fit if you consider them as [cross-account resource-based policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic-cross-account.html) at which point both sides need to grant permission to an action for it to actually be allowed.

Comment: By second case you mean where the principal is "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:root", right? I agree that it would be tough to actually allow anything in the account to assume in that case. However, I think there is no alternative. Like statet in https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/security/how-to-use-trust-policies-with-iam-roles/ there is no wildcard (except only *) or something like "roles starting with <something>" - only conditions are possible. Thus my question what the rule behind this is. It's not identity-based, it's not resource-based, it's kind of both. Feels like something is missing.

Comment: @Bambino It seems to me that the goal with trust relationships (and probably KMS key policies) is probably to simply be more strict since they are security critical and makes sense to never allow everyone to do something with them but to force the user of those systems to always be more specific and think about what user is allowed to do what. I can absolutely understand your confusion, I just accept that those policies behave that way and to me it makes sense.

Comment: @Bambino afaik in cross-account setups resource-based policies require both sides to allow access, e.g. both the account where the bucket is located needs to grant me access but my role also needs a policy that grants me S3 operations on that bucket. In that sense the trust relationship could be considered to be similar to such a cross-account resource-based policy.

Comment: I like your comparison with cross-account setup. Afaik it works the same, yes. Another reference may help where my confusion comes from: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html - trust relationships don't show up in the evaluation logic. What comes closest are once again resource-based policies.

Comment: @Bambino it makes sense for them to not show up, because at the end of the they are just something special and should not clutter the docs for all other interactions. *I* would consider them resource-based policies with the special cross-account handling, even if that is not a perfect fit.