# can IAM user assume a role, whose trust policy allows the user, without explicit AssumeRole permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, roles, identity-management

I have a IAM role with full ec2 access with below trust policy,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::AccountA:user/dev"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

IAM user, dev, does not have an associated AssumeRole policy, but still be able to switch to this role.

When I expand the principal to "Account Number", as expected, I need to attach explicit AssumeRole to user(s) to switch to that role.

can someone explain why a trust policy at user level is not enforcing explicit permission?

Comment: What exactly do you want explained? You already discovered that granting it to a specific user you do not need a role policy additionally, at least not in a cross account situation. It simply is that way, AWS decided to implement it this way.

Comment: ok I got it. so trust policy is acting as an implicit grant here.

Comment: Trust policy is like a resource policy but not exactly. If you grant a user access to a bucket via the bucket policy you do not need an identity based policy on top of it.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70772170/2442804 trust policies are simply a bit special and different to everything else.